# Python: How to count average length of lines in a text file

Tags: python

I'm having trouble defining a function that takes a filename as a parameter and returns the average line length. Particularly having trouble removing the "\n" in the file.

This is what I have so far:

```
    def averageLineLength(fn):
        fn = open("Ex_file.txt", "r")
        lines = fn.readlines()
        return (sum(len(line) for line in lines) / len(lines))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strip()` to remove preceding and trailing `\n` from the line and minor modification to your own code should be sufficient

```
   def averageLineLength(fn):
        fn = open("Ex_file.txt", "r")
        lines = fn.readlines()
        return sum([len(line.strip('\n')) for line in lines]) / len(lines)
```

This cleans out all leading and trailing whitespace. If you only want to strip out \n at the end of the line

```
(sum(len(line.replace("\n",'')) for line in lines) / len(lines))
```

Comment: Oops, that was to be an edit of my own question but no harm :-) Now this is a good answer +1 :))

Comment: @e4c5 I did think it was supposed to be edit to your own question, but then I thought may be I was missing something and you just wanted to point it out. :)

Comment: How can there be `\n` that's not at the end of a line? Wouldn't you have 2 or more lines then?

Comment: @PaulHankin I do not clearly understand your question. My solution is based on an assumption that every line has a trailing `\n`. If you are saying that if a line has a preceding `\n`, wouldn't that make a separate blank line in the file itself or lets say a `\n` in a between a line will break line in the file itself.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar you say in your answer: "If you only want to strip out \n at the end of the line..." and then proceed to show a solution which handles `\n` anywhere in the string. I'm questioning whether that makes sense. (Also, in your first block of code `sum[...]` should be `sum(...)` I think).

Comment: Thank you for this, you're missing a right bracket in your last line, after the "('\n')"

Answer (score 0):

The common way to get rid of whitespace (such as newlines) in python is `strip`.  There's also `rstrip` if you want to preserve the left side, and you can give any of them an argument if you only want to target newlines specifically:

```
>>> '   Hello,    world  \n'.strip()
'Hello,    world'
>>> '   Hello,    world  \n'.rstrip()
'   Hello,    world'
>>> '   Hello,    world  \n'.strip('\n')
'   Hello,    world  '
```

Two other notes:  The original function did not actually use the filename, and in Python 2 it also performs integer division (which may or may not be intentional).  With these modifications:

```
def averageLineLength(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
    return 1.0 * sum(map(len, lines)) / len(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have already will tell you the average line length.

There are a few different methods for handling removal of the '\n'.

The simplest is to just use the "strip" method.  This will remove all leading and trailing whitespace from each line.

If you want to remove only the trailing '\n'.  You can write a simple list comprehension like this to do so.

```
[l[:-1] if l[-1] == "\n" else l for l in lines]
```

Or simply remove the final character without checking, trusting it is a '\n' because you used "readlines".

```
[l[:-1] for l in lines]
```

You should also use the "with" construction block on your file to ensure it is closed when the program exits the block.  Making these changes, your function becomes the following:

```
def averageLineLength(fn):
    with open("Ex_file.txt", "r") as fn:
        lines = [l.strip() for l in fn.readlines()]
    return (sum(len(line) for line in lines) / len(lines)
```

Or alternatively, if you want to preserve leading and trailing whitespace that is not '\n':

```
def averageLineLength(fn):
    with open("Ex_file.txt", "r") as fn:
        lines = [l[:-1] for l in fn.readlines()]
    return (sum(len(line) for line in lines) / len(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should solve the problem as well:

```
def averageLineLength(fn):
    with open('Ex_file.txt".txt', 'r') as fn:
        lst = fn.readlines() 
        return sum([len(line.strip()) for line in lst]) / len(lst)
```